# python asyncio Transport asynchronous methods vs coroutines

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm new to asyncio and I started working with Transports to create a simple server-client program.
on the asyncio page I see the following:

> Transport.close() can be called immediately after WriteTransport.write() even if data are not sent yet on the socket: both methods are asynchronous. yield from is not needed because these transport methods are not coroutines.

I searched the web (including stackoverflow) but couldn't find a good answer to the following question: what are the major differences between an asynchronous method and a coroutine?
The only 2 differences I can make are:

1. in coroutines you have a more fine grained control over the order of the methods the main loop executes using the `yield from` expression.
2. coroutines are generators, hence are more memory efficient.

anything else I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the context *asynchronous* means both `.write()` and `.close()` are regular methods, not coroutines.

If `.write()` cannot write data immediately it stores the data in internal buffer.

`.close()` never closes connection immediately but schedules socket closing after all internal buffer will be sent.

So

```
transp.write(b'data')
transp.write(b'another data')
transp.close()
```

is safe and perfectly correct code.

Also `.write()` and `.close()` are not coroutines, obviously.
You should call coroutine via `yield from` expression, e.g. `yield from coro()`.

But these methods are convention functions, so call it without `yield from` as shown in example above.